# Walkthrough Entire Multidimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a dummy array, that I want to order.

How can I have following result

with foreach?
with while next()
with RecursiveIterator
with IteratorIterator

which one is the fastest?

Here is array

```
$files = array (
  0 => 'do-update.php',
  1 => 'sitemap.xml',
  2 => 'sitemap.xml.gz',
  3 => 'wp-config.php',
  'wp-content' => 
  array (
    'uploads' => 
    array (
      2013 => 
      array (
        '05' => 
        array (
          0 => 'kabeduvarkad-1024x768.jpg',
          1 => 'kabeduvarkad-150x150.jpg',
          2 => 'kabeduvarkad-300x225.jpg',
          3 => 'kabeduvarkad-940x198.jpg',
        ),
        10 => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      2014 => 
      array (
        '02' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      2015 => 'de.php',
    ),
  ),
  'wp-update' => 
  array (
    0 => 'wp-update.tar',
    1 => 'wp-update.tar.gz',
    2 => 'wp-update1.tar',
    3 => 'wp-update1.tar.gz',
  ),
  4 => 'wp-update.tar.gz',
);
```

Expected Result

```
$expected = array (
  0 => 'do-update.php',
  1 => 'sitemap.xml',
  2 => 'sitemap.xml.gz',
  3 => 'test.php',
  4 => 'wp-config.php',
  5 => 'wp-content/',
  6 => 'wp-content/uploads/',
  7 => 'wp-content/uploads/2013/',
  8 => 'wp-content/uploads/2013/05/',
  9 => 'wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-1024x768.jpg',
  10 => 'wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-150x150.jpg',
  11 => 'wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-300x225.jpg',
  12 => 'wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad-940x198.jpg',
  13 => 'wp-content/uploads/2013/05/kabeduvarkad.jpg',
  14 => '...'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) is what you're looking for.

Example (not tested):

```
$expected = [];

array_walk_recursive($your_array, function($item, $key) {
    // push item on to $expected
    $expected[] = $item;
});
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.org/coVl364c)

Comment: Oh yeah, completely missed that requirement. You might have to write a foreach loop, and use `is_array()` to recurse when needed.